# Python3 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to rename a file with non unicode chars in name.

```
import os

dir = b'/tr2'

for file_name in os.listdir(dir):
    file_name = file_name.decode('utf8','replace')
    print(file_name)
    os.rename(file_name,'11.txt')
```

Can only print this name, but when I try to rename, I get the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf1' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Which line is this happening on? On `print(file_name)` (trying to print unicode data to a terminal that can't handle unicode) or on `os.rename(file_name, '11.txt')`? Please always include the _full_ stack trace. Also, you shouldn't really need to decode the binary file name, it should work if you pass it  to `os.rename` as returned by `os.listdir`

Comment: I have trobles exacly with rename line 10, in <module>
    os.rename(file_name,'11.txt')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf1' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128). And when I remove file_name = file_name.decode('utf8','replace'), I got error - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'01 Contrase\xc3\xb1as.txt' -> '11.txt'

Comment: `os.rename()` works relative to the current directory, the files returned by `os.listdir()` are relative to the given path (`dir = b'/tr2'`), that's why you get a FileNotFoundError. try `os.rename(os.path.join(dir, file_name), os.path.join(dir, b'11.txt'))` without decoding file_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in that I needed to display the value of the file_name and work with it later in the program. So thanks to Martin Evans the decision in the next:

```
import os

dir = b'/tr2'

for file_name in os.listdir(dir):

print(file_name.decode('utf8','replace'))

os.rename(os.path.join(dir, file_name), os.path.join(dir, b'11.txt'))
```